# Retrieving Dynamic XML contents into a variable in Perl

Tags: javascript, xml, perl

I am trying to retrieve content from a dynamic XML generated in Perl proxy. here is the code,

```
$show=$query->param('id_show');
$lang=$query->param('id_lang');


$filename="http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=".$show."&language=".$lang;


print "$filename </br>";
print "End of Program";

# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
# create object
$xml = new XML::Simple;
# read XML file
$data = $xml->XMLin("$filename");

print "$data </br>";
```

Now the error which is being shown to me is :

```
File does not exist: http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=Fringe&language=English at /cgi-bin/mytest.pl line 37
```

I later on want to send this xml contents to javascript where JS will parse the contents and display.

Comment: What is the value of `$show`?

Comment: $show has fringe and $lang has english. As you can see i have also pasted the formed url

Comment: Well, where did `"seriesname="` go?

Comment: so the thing is : i take user parameters show,lang and create a dynamic url using those parameters. To avoid cross domain restrictions i am using Perl proxy. Now when the url is formed it returns a xml in browser. i wish to wrap this xml object into some object and send it to the javascript program i have.

Comment: Right, that's not what I'm asking about.  When you define `$filename`, the string `"seriesname="` is a substring of `$filename`.  However, when you print out `$filename`, the string `"seriesname="` is **not** a substring of `$filename`.  Where did the substring go?

Comment: Also, you need to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Always.

Comment: sorry that was a typo when i edited the question. fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's because `XML::Simple::XMLin()` method doesn't work with HTTP links, I suppose. The only legit sources of data it might use are filenames, IO::Handle objects, and strings.

Try to fetch the content of this link with `LWP::Simple` module (it exports very convenient function `get()` right for this case), like this:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get($url_goes_here);
```

...then pass the resulting $content to the XMLin.